# Python / Pandas - Transposing part of a dataframe and grouping keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
b_id        conta      valor
302          12.3       123
303          12.3       323
302          11.4       674
...
```

I'm having quite a hard time trying to make it look like this:

```
b_id    12.3     11.4 ...
 302     123      674
 303     323      NaN
 ...
```

Already tried different merges, concats and joins but I haven't been successful, nothing appears to make it look like this.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
df = df.pivot(index='b_id', columns='conta', values='valor')
print (df)
conta   11.4   12.3
b_id               
302    674.0  123.0
303      NaN  323.0
```

```
df = df.set_index(['b_id', 'conta'])['valor'].unstack()
print (df)
conta   11.4   12.3
b_id               
302    674.0  123.0
303      NaN  323.0
```

If duplicates in columns created new index and columns:

```
print (df)
   b_id  conta  valor
0   302   12.3    123<-b_id=302, conta=12.3
1   302   12.3    100<-b_id=302, conta=12.3
2   303   12.3    323
3   302   11.4    674
```

... then need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function like `mean`, `sum` or use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `aggregate function` + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='b_id', columns='conta', values='valor', aggfunc='mean')
print (df)
conta   11.4   12.3
b_id               
302    674.0  111.5
303      NaN  323.0

df = df.groupby(['b_id', 'conta'])['valor'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
conta   11.4   12.3
b_id               
302    674.0  111.5
303      NaN  323.0
```